# I need a little clarification on dynamically setting a hover BG

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```
function recordStarted() {
$("#red_button").css("background","url(stop.png)");
$("#red_button").css("background-repeat","no-repeat");

$("#red_button:hover").css("background","url(stop-hover.png)");
$("#red_button:hover").css("background-repeat","no-repeat");
}
```

I have the background of the div layer being set by the second line, but when I try to set the hover background, it just becomes the background. How would I go about setting the :hover background dynamically?

CSS:

```
.red_button 
{
background:url(record.png);
padding: 19px 251px;
cursor: pointer;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.red_button:hover 
{
background:url(record-hover.png);
cursor: pointer;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: You don't do this with PHP.

Comment: sorry, css in javascript in a php file. How would you go about it?

Comment: in your javascript you are targeting an element by the id `#red_button` but in your css you are targeting elements with the class `.red_button` is this intentional? does the element with the id `red_button` also have a class `red_button`? (i.e. `<button id="red_button" class="red_button">Text</button>`)

Comment: I didn't write this piece of the code. I'm just trying to fix something in it. I'm not sure if that was intentional or not

Comment: Would you be able to post the html to go along with this? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's jQuery. :hover is not part of a jQuery selector. You can do that in css. But if you are for some reason determined to doing in it jQuery, what you should do is to assign to your css the background image of stop.png to #red_button. Then add also to your css #red_button.hover and assign the other image to it as a background. Then in jQuery use

```
$("#red_button").hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I followed your example or got it from someone else, but this is exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks for answering and sorry it took so long to mark your answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use css to do this:

```
#red_button {
  background: "url(stop.png)";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#red_button:hover {
  background: "url(stop-hover.png)";
}
```

Comment: That could work except, I've already set a background and am simply changing it, but need to change the hover background as well. Check the edit to my answer for my css code

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure to see the issue. You can always play adding more selector if you need more weight such as #red_button.hover if you add a class hover to your element.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript to do this, css is all that is required. I recommend using a css sprite system so that a second image does not need to be downloaded when the button is hovered on, this can cause the button to appear to vanish for a moment while the hover image is loaded.

Essentially with CSS Sprites you would have an image that contains both the default and hovered state next to each other, the button would then operate like a window whereby the correct part of the image would be moved into view using the `background-position` CSS property depending on the state.

(I know everyone hates W3Schools but this is is a good tutorial for a basic concept)

Check out the following tutorial to learn more about CSS spiriting.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp