# Change CSS properties using Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dynamic

I'm trying to adjust my CSS dynamically. Here's my CSS:

```
.red_button {
  background:url(record.png);
  padding: 19px 251px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.red_button:hover {
  background:url(record-hover.png);
  cursor: pointer;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Which after it is clicked gets changed to something like this:

```
function recordStarted() {
  started = true;
  $("#red_button").css("background","url(stop.png)");
  $("#red_button").css("background-repeat","no-repeat");
}
```

But if I try to change the :hover attribute with something like `$("#red_button:hover").css("background","url(stop.png)");` it just changes the background (not the hover background). So what is the best way to go about this? I have tried a few different things like with jQuery, but have not been able to get anything to work.

Comment: please add the fiddle so that we can undstnd what is the exact problem

Comment: This approach seems unclear - it's better to create another css class, rather than altering element styles in js

Comment: You already have `.red_button:hover` rule, why are trying to reset it in JS?

Comment: This is for a video recording widget, so the first click records the video and changes the button to a "Stop Recordng" button, which itself has a regular and a :hover image

Comment: @Christian I updated my answer now that I fully understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question/answer ended up answering my question pretty adequately.

[I need a little clarification on dynamically setting a hover BG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237917/i-need-a-little-clarification-on-dynamically-setting-a-hover-bg)

Answer (score 1):

Please don't do this, use a CSS class unless absolutely required. This will separate all your styling into CSS where it belongs and clean up your JS at the same time.

**CSS**

```css
#red_button.clicked {
    /* Applied when the button is clicked and NOT hovered */
}

#red_button.clicked:hover {
    /* Applied when the button is clicked and hovered */
    background: url(stop.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**JS**

```
function recordStarted() {
    started = true;
    $("#red_button").addClass("clicked");
}
```

I also notice that you are referring to the `.red_button` class in CSS but the `#red_button` ID in JS, you probably mean for them both to be IDs?

**EDIT:** Change the rule to apply when clicked and hovered.

Here is a simple example of the styles in action: http://jsfiddle.net/BMmsD/

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$("#red_button").mouseover(function() {
   this.css("background","url(stop.png)");
});
```

Comment: You need `$(this)` because `this` is not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

You doing some typo error I guess as you are using `"."` in css and `"#"` in jquery.

else use `updated code`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".red_button").click(function() {
        $(".red_button").css("background","record-hover.png");
    });
});
```

I hope I am clear enough ?

Comment: So, if I make them the same, I can use the :hover element in the javascript?

Comment: you u need hover from javascript ?? its simple hover you want i guess..use css only

Comment: No, but I already have a :hover set up in css. I am changing the background image with a click though with javascript and need to change the :hover element to match it.